# ajax cache false not working to load image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to load image from server when ever i click a button by using get request but every time i load using ajax it bring cached image not the latest one

here is my code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({ url:"cap", cache: false });

 $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#mydiv").load("cap");
    });
});

</script>


             <div style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;">

             <div id='mydiv'></div>
            </div>
            <button id='btn'  > reload  </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you integrate a `<img>` tag into the `<div id='mydiv'></div>`? Then you could change the `src` attribute in order to change the image and you don't need to use ajax.

You can refresh your image, when you add a unique string to your image request.

For example you can get a image by calling:

`<img src="http://www.example.com/pictures/img.png?123">`

`<img src="http://www.example.com/pictures/img.png?456">`

That's a way to avoid caching. In order to do this dynamically you can use the date object and add the current date to your URL.

`$("#myImg").prop("src", "myImg.png?" + new Date().valueOf());`

Comment: the image captcha it is created by php when ever i load the page cap

Comment: and what is the problem with that?